# What kind of components are expected to be saved in ansible tmp folder during execution of a task?

Tags: ansible

I am investigating an issue with ansible and suspect whether a registered variable was saved in ansible tmp folder, because I also suspect that such temporary directory is being removed by `async_wrapper` module during execution (the environment is based on ansible 2.2 and there is a known [issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/10855) with `async_wrapper` module).

Therefore I would like to know what kind of items are expected to be saved in ansible tmp folder such as in `.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-xxx...` during execution of a task. Then at least it would be possible to make some further estimations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:
`export ANSIBLE_KEEP_REMOTE_FILES=1`

This will retain the files that Ansible copies to `.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-xxx...` and runs on the destination host.

Set the env variable before running the playbook with -vvv. This will output the paths used to store the scripts on the destination host.

After the playbook has completed. SSH onto the destination host and take a look at the files.

The files are most likely on a path like:

`/home/user/.ansible/tmp/..../modulename`

The easiest way to view/test them is to explode them and then execute them.

```
python /home/user/.ansible/tmp/..../modulename explode
```

This will create a subdirectory containing the module, arguments and ansible wrapper.

```
python /home/user/.ansible/tmp/..../modulename execute
```

This will run the exploded files.

You will be able to see from this exactly what is being saved where. It's also possible to edit the module and test to see what changes are made to the `/tmp` folder.